# does any one know how to add a tooltip in the code behind of uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

hi I'm trying to add a text window that opens when I hover over a image in Uwp
I'm not meant to use xaml and I'm having troubles I pretty much want it to do this:
  `ToolTip tp = new ToolTip(); tp.Content = this.ToString(); ToolTipService.SetPlacementTarget(tp,Img);`
but i cant get it to be added to the image any help would be appreciated.
does any one know what to do?

Comment: tp.Content = this.ToString();  What this 'this' is?

Answer (score 1):

Call SetToolTip() with the image as the first parameter.

```
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(image, "this is my tip");
```